# google translate element is not working on mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, translation

i used below code to translate my website from the language Eng - Arabic.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js? 
cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en' , includedLanguages : 'ar,xx,yy,en', 
layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
```

its working fine in laptop view.but when i test it on mobile view its not working properly.and also i set a new language translation code in mobile view.and call the same script.

```
<!-- laptop view-->
<div id="google_translate_element" class="trans" style="padding:0px;"  ></div> 

   
        



         <!-- mob view-->
          <div id="google_translate_element" style="padding:0px;">
            <div class="skiptranslate goog-te-gadget" dir="ltr" style="">
              <div id=":0.targetLanguage">
                <select class="goog-te-combo" aria-label="Language Translate Widget" style="padding: 5px;
background: azure;
font-size: 15px;
border-radius: 10px;
font-weight: 700 !important;">
                  <option value="">Select Language</option>
                  <option value="ar">Arabic</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

when i comment the mobile view code, 2 select box appearing on mobile view and working fine with mobile view and not in laptop view [the website link given here](https://appsyncdesigns.com/test/pckart/)

Comment: can anyone helps me??